# A glob to shallowly match directories

Tags: regex, node.js, glob

Here is an example of cases and whether they should match or not:

```
foo/node_modules -> yep

foo/bar/node_modules -> yep

foo/bar/node_modules/baz/node_modules -> matches only foo/bar/node_modules

foo/node_modules/bar/node_modules -> matches only foo/node_modules

node_modules/foo/node_modules/bar -> matches only node_modules
```

---

**EDIT**

This did the trick for 2 levels deep:

```
const patterns = [
  '*/node_modules',
  '*/!(node_modules)/node_modules',
  '*/!(node_modules)/*/node_modules',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`glob`](https://pymotw.com/2/glob/) rules are *"applied to segments of the filename (stopping at the path separator, `/`)."* This means that you can't perform any wildcard matches that span across multiple depths, which is crucial for your question. The only way I see to accomplish this question directly is to use many searches (and stopping after the first match), for example:

- `ls node_modules`
- `ls */node_modules`
- `ls */*/node_modules`
- `ls */*/*/node_modules`
- etc.

---

However, this can be [accomplished with a regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/vE0kS0/1):

```
^.*?node_modules(?=\/|$)
```

---

Or, you could use Node.JS to recursively loop through directories until you hit the first instance of `node_modules` and return the path.

Comment: Thanks mate! Great answer.